# Start list from a specific element

Tags: pandas, indexing, row

I would like to ask you one simple question.

Namely, I have a dataframe with a column containing multiple rows like this:

```
10712   99883522686 [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
10714   9998240348  [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
10715   99997364349 [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
```

I would like to redesign this list to start from its third element only if the third element is number 12 like in this example here so that I get a lists in all of my rows that would look like this.

```
10712   99883522686 [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
10714   9998240348  [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
10715   99997364349 [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
```

Thank you.

```
def transform_row(row):
    if row["months"][2] == 12:
        new_list = row["months"][2:] + row["months"][:2]
    else:
        new_list = row["months"]
    return new_list


df["months"] = df.apply(transform_row, axis=1)

print(df)
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension.

To slice only if 12 is the 3rd item:

```
df['month'] = [l[2:] if l[2]==12 else l for l in df['month']]
```

Or to start whenever 12 is found:

```
df['month'] = [l[l.index(12):] for l in df['month']]
```

Or, if 12 is always the 3rd item:

```
df['month'] = [l[2:] for l in df['month']]
```

Output:

```
       A            B                            month
0  10712  99883522686  [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1  10714   9998240348  [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2  10715  99997364349  [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10712, 10714, 10715],
                   'B': [99883522686, 9998240348, 99997364349],
                   'month': [[10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                             [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                             [10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

If need test third element by `12` and then filter use:

```
m = df["months"].str[2].eq(12)

df['months'] = df['months'].mask(m, df["months"].str[2:])
```